# I cannot execute a program in a container when working with Apptainer becaouse the path is not found

Tags: singularity-container

I have pulled a Docker container to create the .sif file

```
apptainer pull docker://mblanche/ngmerge:latest
```

there is no documentation so I have explored the sif file to know where is the tool I want to use is.

```
apptainer run  /mainfs/wrgl/broadinstitute_warp_development/warp/images/manuel_images/ngmerge_latest.sif /bin/bash

# In the container I have found the tool
cd /
cd NGmerge/
ls 
LICENSE  Makefile  NEWS  NGmerge.c  NGmerge.h  README.md  UserGuide.pdf  VERSION  figures  qual_profile.txt  scripts

# If I do 

NGmerge

# The tool is run
```

The executable NGmerge works when I'm in its directory because (I think) the current directory (.) is in the PATH. However, when trying to execute it directly with the full path from outside the container or in the container from another directory, it's not being found, indicating a potential issue with the path or executable.

How can I run the executable in this situation??

Comment: OK.
I solve this doing this ``` apptainer run  ngmerge_latest.sif /bin/bash -c "cd /NGmerge && NGmerge " ```